# How to Store HTTP Request Code in separate class for Reusability?

Tags: rest-api, json, httprequest, after-trigger

We have JSON HTTP Post request that triggers from  one salesforce object to external system and we want to extend this functionality for other object. This code Fires and creates a Record in external system when the criteria matches. We want to have this functionality on other object in salesforce. I know we can Reuse the code and I don't want to end up creating another Class that does the same thing for different criteria. how do I store HTTP Request in separate class/method and Call out that whenever I need to

Here is the code

```
public class RadarUpdate {
@future (callout=true)
public static void postcallout(string Id) { 
//querying patient relations record
Patient_Satisfaction__c c = [select id,Name, Patient_First_Name__c,Patient_Last_Name__c, Reporter_Phone__c,Reporter_First_Name__c,Reporter_Last_Name__c, Reporter_Email__c,
Description_of_Feedback__c from Patient_Satisfaction__c where Patient_Relation__c ='Referred to Privacy Office' order by lastmodifiedDate desc limit 1];
//generating JSON 
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeObjectField('name', c.Patient_Last_Name__c + ', ' + c.Patient_First_Name__c);
gen.writeObjectField('incident_group_id', 7448);
gen.writeObjectField('description',c.Description_of_Feedback__c);
gen.writeFieldName('submitted_by');
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('given_name',c.Reporter_First_Name__c);
gen.writeStringField('surname', c.Reporter_Last_Name__c);
gen.writeStringField('phone',c.Reporter_Phone__c);
gen.writeStringField('email',c.Reporter_Email__c);
gen.writeEndObject();
gen.writeFieldName('custom');
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('TRIPSS ID',c.Name);
gen.writeEndObject();
String jsonS = gen.getAsString(); 
System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jsonS);
//generating Http request
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.radarfirst.com/incidents');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.setHeader('User-agent', 'Salesforce-integration-client');
request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU0');
request.setBody(jsonS);
// Set the body as a JSON object
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
    response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
System.debug(response.getBody());
}
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, not sure if that answers my question. Its just that I'm learning Apex and doesn't want to repeat the same code for other object.

Comment: It's an open source library you can use to achieve your goal. If you'd like to do it yourself, you can take a look at its source code and learn from it.